# Conflict between two React when I'm using component from NextJS from an external lib

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

I'm currently building an external library to store all my common components, but when i'm using a NextJs component I got this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')`

I made a lot's of test and search and found it's appening everytime I'm using a NextJs component with hook (NextLink use useRef, NextImage use useContext, ..) but the error seems to be because I'm using 2 different React (one on the lib, and another one from the project using the lib).

I conclude that my issue come from the way I'm building the lib (using yarm) but cannot found any solution..

## The lib

In  `package.json` I put React into peerDependancies to not be imported

```
{

  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "yarn": "^1.22.19"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.19",
  "scripts": {
    "dist:cjs": "tsc --project tsconfig-cjs.json",
    "dist:esm": "tsc --project tsconfig.json",
    "dist": "yarn run dist:cjs & yarn run dist:esm"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "./dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "./dist/esm/index.js",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "*",
    "react": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "*",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.12",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "next": "^12.0.7",
    "react": "*",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "2.0.2",
    "@chakra-ui/theme-tools": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

I'm using `tsc --project tsconfig.json` to compile the Lib with this `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "module": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,

    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist/esm",
    "target": "es2020",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",

    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,

    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,

    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "newLine": "lf",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "preserveWatchOutput": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

##### Example of working component

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
import React from 'react'

export function TestHook() :JSX.Element {
  const count = useRef(0);
  return (
    <>
      Hello {JSON.stringify(count)}
    </>
  );
}
```

##### Example of not working component (from NextJS)

```
import NextLink, { LinkProps as NextLinkProps } from 'next/link'
import React from 'react'

export function NavLink({ href, ...props }: Pick<NextLinkProps, 'href'>) {
  return (
    <NextLink {...{ href }} passHref>
      <a {...props} />
    </NextLink>
  )
}
```

## The project

I'm using git submodules in order to link the library into my project (at `./modules/Lib`), then I installed it using `file://`

`package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "my-lib": "file:modules/Lib",
    "next": "12.2.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "4.8.2"
  }
```

From this project I can use `TestHook` component from the lib without any issue, or `NavLink` when it's directly on the project:

```
import React from 'react'

import { TestHook } from 'my-lib'
import { NavLink } from './NavLink'

export function Home() :JSX.Element {
  return (
    <>
     <TestHook />
     <NavLink href={"/"}>Home</NavLink>
    </>
  );
}
```

But when I got the error when I try to use `NavLink` from the Lib:

```
import React from 'react'

import { TestHook, NavLink } from 'my-lib'

export function Home() :JSX.Element {
  return (
    <>
     <TestHook />
     <NavLink href={"/"}>Home</NavLink>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
```

Comment: What is the `package.json` of mylib? Please indicate the projects in your question files

Comment: I included both package.json on my question. The first is the from the lib, and the second is from the project. Did I forget something?

Comment: I updated the package.json file to include more information (and not only dependencies) in case it's useful

Comment: You basically need a way to exclude React and ReactDOM from the bundled code of your library. Not sure if this can be done with Typescript's compiler alone. If not, look up "externals" in Webpack or Rollup.